# sqllite PDO query fails on query with IN operator

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

My PHP is 5.2.13

phpInfo() shows:

PECL Module version     1.0.1 $Id: pdo_sqlite.c 293036 2010-01-03 09:23:27Z sebastian $

SQLite Library  3.3.7undefined

Following query runs without any errors

```
$stmt = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM Przepis WHERE rodzajPrzepisu = 1');
```

however if I change it to

```
$stmt = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM Przepis WHERE rodzajPrzepisu IN (1, 2)');
```

I get following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 14 unable to open database file

Please point me what I am doing wrong or maybe there is a bung in sqlite driver I'm using?

Kind Regards
  Kragh